# Where is the safest place to be in a zombie Apocalypse

Tags: apocalypse, zombies, safety

Where would be the safest place to be in a zombie Apocalypse?  For example I would think a large ship would be a good place to be as you could turn seawater into drinking water, you can fish, if the deck is big enough you could grow vegetables. Also you would be safe enough from the zombies assuming they can't swim. 
By safe I mean highest chance of survival so things like,
Lowest risk of being killed by zombies, 
Ability to get food and water.
Anything else necessary to survive.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange:worldbuilding. We try to avoid opinion-based posts, and this is something that is most certainly opinion based. What can you add to your question to help separate good questions from bad ones? What criteria does a safe place meet?

Comment: And what do you do when one of the people on the ship spontaneously goes Z? Where will you run?

Comment: I edited to try make less opinion based. I guess if people on the ship turned your options would be close the fire doors, get in life boats or if it was a military ship you would have plenty of guns at your disposal.

Comment: You can edit the question to give limits to what the zombie can do, so people can actually figure where is the safest place. If your zombie can fly, a ship will not be a safest place, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

1. No new people are being let onto this structure arbitrarily.
2. It's not an especially virulent airborne agent causing the zombies.

Then technically yes, being out to sea would make you safe from the zombies. It would not, however, protect you from a number of problems both logistical and scientific that would come from such a thing.

Ships exist that can carry upwards of a few thousand people in closed quarters, but this is for a limited engagement, even the military ships dock for resupply, crew exchange and shore leave.

You need at least 100 people, none of whom are related, and all of whom are capable of reproducing, to replenish the human race assuming these will be the sole survivors in the long run.

100 people, living and also reproducing exponentially, will run out of room very quickly. And by run out or room, I don't mean "there just won't be standing room". The human psyche can only stand being cramped and crowded for so long before other kinds of madness not zombie in nature would show themselves.

You also need to feed this population, and you'd need more room than the deck of the ship to grow enough vegetables. You could eat marine life for protein, but when you're hunting that wild in the sea around you, there's little guarantee of the abundance modern aquaculture and industrial fishing affords us.

You're also at the mercy of maritime weather indefinitely, which has sunk even the mightiest ships.

There's also the fuel (and power sources), resources to replace and repair things, and other issues that make staying off land permanently not that viable.

Also, desalinating water isn't easy to do, to meet the needs of a population even as small as 100 people, if rigged arbitrarily like that.

So would you be safe from zombies? yes. Would you survive in the long run? Probably not. It'd be better to choose a large enough uninhabited island with actual land, fresh water and so on, and establish your colony there. There are plenty of these in the pacific even now.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a castle or fortified town. In Europe for example, I would go to Dubrovnik.

[image]
[image]